# how to convert from english to predicate logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I need help converting this sentence to predicate logic:
'Every boy who loves all girls does not love every boy'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community It's not at all unclear what he's asking.

Answer (score 0):

B is the set of all boys

G is the set of all girls

L(x, y) is read as "x likes y"

The statement will be:

$\forall x\in B(\forall y\in G:L(x, y)\implies\neg\forall z\in B:L(x, z))$

Or equivalently:

$\forall x\in B(\forall y\in G:L(x, y)\implies\exists z\in B:\neg L(x, z))$